# Filter data from file get contents or curl

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I am trying to get some information from an website. I load the website with file_get_contents or even using curl.

The page has no html, it`s just text, formatted like this:

Name: x
Email: y
Phone: z

Kinda like 20.000 entries.

Is there any way I can get these entries to an array or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));

fclose ($fd); 
$delimiter = " ";
$splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $contents);
$counter = "";
```

Garnered from [here](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/article.php?article=165). If you should need further assistance, please leave a comment.

Comment: How is this helping me? I have 20.000 names, 20.000 emails and 20.000 phone numbers. I want all this data formatted into an array with 20.000 entries (phone, email, name).

Comment: Save the names, emails, and phone numbers to a temporary file and read that in using the code.

Comment: I need them grouped. There is no comma between data or anything. Looks exactly like this:

Name: Tom
Email: tom@x.com
Phone: 07592222

Name: Jim
Email: Jim@x.com
Phone: 12121211

Comment: Where did you get comma from? My code uses a space as the delimiter. Anyway, did you even bother to test it out?

Comment: No, because i need all the information grouped into an array. Following the example before: array(array('Name' => 'Jim', 'Email' => 'Jim@x.com', 'Phone' => '12121211'), array('Name' => 'Tom', 'Email' => 'Tom@x.com', 'Phone' => '07592222')). Is your code making that? :)

Comment: I'm not a PHP interpreter, you clearly have one on your system. Further you have the data you need to process. Why don't you try it out and report back instead of whinging?

Comment: Writing 20.000 values on a text file is not an option for me. If I have 100.000 tomorrow and 1 million in 2 days?

Comment: To quote from Yes Minister, that is YP -- Your Problem.